# HTML 5 VIDEO + JQUERY Swapping between 2 videos including fallbacks, and not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, video, swap

html+video files at: dausign.com/clicktohearsound

Howdy, I'm working on a simple video piece where I have a button that swaps the video and the button disappears. I have 2 videos each with 2 fallbacks. Would anyone know why the video is not showing up in firefox? Also, if I wanted to go back to the first video with the button by clicking in the window, what would be the best way to achieve that? thankseeeeee

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got an extra closing parenthesis on line 122.